# In CoffeeScript, is it possible to increment a for loop manually?

Tags: coffeescript

My CoffeeScript is as follows:

```
for i in [1..3]
  i++ if i is 1
  console.log i
```

Expected output is

```
2
3
```

Generated output is

```
2
2
3
```

The issue is that CoffeeScript keeps a private variable to keep track of the iteration, `_i`, but if I try to increment that `_i++`, then the private variable changes to `_j` and constantly evades me.

So how can I increment the loop manually using CoffeeScript?

Comment: Why not use `[2..3]` instead of `[1..3]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't manually increment the loop's counting variable. Instead, you need to use `continue` to skip one or more iterations.

```
for i in [1..3]
  continue if i is 1
  console.log i
```

You should never attempt to access or modify CoffeeScript's generate variables, those are an implementation detail and you cannot rely on them being present.

Comment: You could also use `when i != 1` in this particular case: `for i in [1..3] when i != 1`